# When to finish Intent

Tags: android, android-intent

I've made a ButtomNavigationBar as you can see and every time i selected other item in the bar it started another intent, so when i press the button "back" it goes through all the activities that started.
So the temporary solution that i found its to use finish() every time i select another item, but now when i click two times on the item the application finishes

```js
bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
  @Override
  public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
    int i = item.getItemId();
    if (i == R.id.navigation_home) {
      item.setCheckable(false);
      finish();
      return true;
    } else if (i == R.id.navigation_dashboard) {
      Intent intent1 = new Intent(Home.this, ActivityOne.class);
      startActivity(intent1);
      item.setCheckable(true);
      finish();
      return true;
    } else if (i == R.id.navigation_notifications) {
      Intent intent2 = new Intent(Home.this, ActivityTwo.class);
      startActivity(intent2);
      item.setCheckable(true);
      finish();
      return true;

    } else if (i == R.id.nav_slideshow) {
      Intent intent3 = new Intent(Home.this, ActivityThree.class);
      startActivity(intent3);
      item.setCheckable(true);
      finish();
      return true;
    }

    return false;
  }

});
```

Comment: What do you mean by "When I click two items?" - You are clicking on two items at the same time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `android:noHistory="true"` in your manifest activity tag instead manually finishing activity every time

when you set `android:noHistory="true"` for an activity then this activity not have any backstack history. that mean if you leave this activity you cannot go back by pressing back button. it's same behaviour as you using `finish();`

you can set this in your manifest like this

```
<application ... >
    <activity android:name="com.example.myapp.MainActivity"
              android:noHistory="true">
    </activity>
</application>
```

remember only set `noHistory` to activities on which you don't want to go back by pressing back

Answer (score 0):

Can this help?

```
bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
    int lastItemId = -1;

    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        int i = item.getItemId();
        if (i == R.id.navigation_home && lastItemId != i) {
            lastItemId = i;
            item.setCheckable(false);
            finish();
            return true;
        } else if (i == R.id.navigation_dashboard && lastItemId != i) {
            lastItemId = i;
            Intent intent1 = new Intent(Home.this, ActivityOne.class);
            startActivity(intent1);
            item.setCheckable(true);
            finish();
            return true;
        } else if (i == R.id.navigation_notifications && lastItemId != i) {
            lastItemId = i;
            Intent intent2 = new Intent(Home.this, ActivityTwo.class);
            startActivity(intent2);
            item.setCheckable(true);
            finish();
            return true;

        } else if (i == R.id.nav_slideshow && lastItemId != i) {
            lastItemId = i;
            Intent intent3 = new Intent(Home.this, ActivityThree.class);
            startActivity(intent3);
            item.setCheckable(true);
            finish();
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

});
```